# Seagate 2TB hardisk file transfer is very slow

Tags: partitioning, usb, hard-drive, external-hdd

Recently file transfer to my external-HDD(Seagate) has become pathetic for some reason. Even on new os it preforms the same.

[image]

Transfer is slower than my internet connection, there should be something related to currupted file system. How to fix this?

Comment: Ageing HDD? Hardware issue?

Comment: It works fine in mac though.

Comment: maybe you plugged it into another USB port than before?